# Left-aligning nested labels in enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to tweak the way nested lists appear for enumerate. Right now, using `enumitem` package, I've got something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=0pt]
  \item First
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=0pt]
    \item Second
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=0pt]
      \item Third
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The above creates a list like:

```
    1. First
  1.1. Second
1.1.1. Third
    2. Fourth
```

And I'd like it to look like:

```
1.     First
1.1.   Second
1.1.1. Third
2.     Fourth
```

This will be an extremely long 'list,' as it is actually a procedure, and could contain hundreds of steps with varying substeps. This is really the one thing I can't seem to figure out for my needs. I believe I can do it with trial/error by customizing varying alignments using `\SetLabelAlign`, but if there's an easier/simpler way - that would be wonderful.

Also, if there's a better way in general to do what I want, (step numbering with nested steps from # to #.#.#.) I'm all ears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting your own alignment to something that contains the enumeration in a fixed-width box. This way you can specify the location to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{fixedwidth}{\hss\llap{\makebox[2.5em][l]{#1}}}
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=0pt,align=fixedwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text before.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Third
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}

\noindent Some text after.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect; that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.,wide =0pt, labelindent = 1em, leftmargin =*]
  \item First Text text text. Text text text.Text text text. Text text text. Text text text. Text text text.Text text text. Text text text.
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.,align = left]
    \item Second Some more text text text. Some more text text text. Some more text text text. Some more text text text. Some more text text text.
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*., align = left]
      \item Third
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]